# VB Script to add whitespaces at end of every sentence

Tags: vbscript

I have to create a script which  does the following:

- takes in a text file as input
- then check to see if each line of the text file is made up of 1464 character.
- If its not, I need to add enough white space to make each line have 1464 characters in total.

I've written the following script but I am getting the following compilation error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'strLine'.
```

Here is the code below

```
 Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFile = "c:\Users\ERP\Documents\testFile.txt"
    strTemp = "c:\Users\ERP\Documents\temp.txt"
    Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
    Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)
    Set ts = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)
    Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = ts.ReadLine
        strLineLength = Len(strLine)
        If strLineLength < 1464 Then
            strDiff = 1464-strLineLength
            strLine.Space(strDiff)
            objOutFile.Write(strLine)
        End If
    Loop
    objOutFile.Close
    ts.Close
    objFS.DeleteFile(strFile)
    objFS.MoveFile strTemp,strFile
```

The error is occurs on this line:

```
strLine.Space(strDiff)
```

Could anyone point me to what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: I would have guessed the error was on this line: `strLine = ts.ReadLine` since the variable was not declared.

Comment: I think you want `strLine = strLine & Space(strDiff)`

Comment: I removed your vb.net and vba tags. This is VBScript, which is quite different from vb.net and slightly different from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
strLine = strLine & Space(strDiff)
```

Space is a method that takes in a number of spaces to return, in dotNet, it is part ot the string class but in VBScript/VBA, I think it is it's own function.  If not, try

```
String.Space(strDiff)
```